# Browser Based Application on IE a spying issue on blue prism. Element gets off screen and bp can't highlight

Tags: object, fullscreen, blueprism, html-mode

I am using citrix vdi to read an element on webpage. It is able to highlight and read the value in open vdi but in close vdi layout of webpage messes up and element i need went out of bound/off screen from webpage. I have tried minimize and maximize before reading value but invain. I also tried html mode and AA still cannot read it. In html mode i kept only path attribute for element, value remains exactly same on close and open vdi. The only difference i have notice is width of div in which element resides. Div width changes in open 1921and close 1203 which i assume push element out of screen bounds. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the width of an element when spying, modern CSS makes it so elements can resize automatically according to window size. That said, I am fairly certain the element being off screen is not an issue; unless you are using region mode spying and have element parameters like 'Visible' unchecked.

Comment: Unfortunately webpage do not resize itself. I have unchecked everything n kept path attribute for element which works fine in open vdi as the web layout is maximize but not in close vdi. How to spy it can you please share.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more clarity to what exactly you're doing when you say you're "Closing" the VDI? Are you closing your remote connection to the VDI? Are you closing the browser window *on* that VDI? Can you also provide a bit more clarity on what exactly you're referring to when you use the term "Citrix VDI?" What specific platform is this? What remote access tool are you using to connect to this VDI?

Answer (score 2):

When working with Blue Prism don’t rely on initial attribute set. You need to choose as few attributes as possible to uniquely identify element. You should always untick attributes that are empty or it’s value it’s “Self” (for example Element ID attribute tends to have such value which doesn’t mean anything). Generally, attributes connected with elements position on the screen or its size are not helpful, because it may be easily affected. 
When working with HTML spy mode your elements don’t need to be visible on screen to interact with them (unless you are using surface automation techniques), HTML elements don’t have any Visible or Screen Visible attributes. 
Try to use attributes like:

- Tag Name
- Class Name
- ID
- If Value has always particular text, use wildcard type of match: *text*

Path attribute is not always the best choice as it might change because web page is dynamic or application update mess up the layout. If you won’t be able to identify element any other way, make sure you use Path as Dynamic match type & store it as environmental variable, so it could be easily adjusted if needed. 
If you have problems reading value using “Get Current Value”, try “Get HTML Attribute” in Read stage options & try “Value” or “Title” as an Input.